# Purpose of permalink in new navigation

Tags: support, new-nav

In the new navigation a "permalink" has been added:

[image]

The tooltip says: "a link to this question list suitable for sharing"

I can't see the purpose of this. Clicking on it, just reloads the page. I'd expect it to copy the link to the system clipboard, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the URL of the freshly reloaded page, it will be different - that's the permalink.

You need to copy and paste that to share it with other people.

It won't copy automatically to the system clipboard... that's a bit *too* much effort for a simple permalink (see [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/3541881) at Stack Overflow).

Comment: But, what page? I went  5 pages down (on my "recent activity") and the permalink still remained the same?

Comment: @HackerKarma not *completely* sure - I opted back in this morning - still waiting to get it back (I opted out yesterday to check something... probs should have used Incognito mode)... but AFAIR that's how the permalink works... I'll update as soon as I get back in!

Comment: @HackerKarma What do you mean with "recent activity"?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no problem... sure.

Comment: @MouseEvent Permalink is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permalink so dynamically generated pages can have a fixed permanent link... I meant to say "recently active"

Comment: So if I get it right, it is just an "insurance" that the link is safe. This means it must not necessarily be clickable. (Since questions don't have permalinks, it always just refers to the listing, that _is_ always permanent.)

Comment: @MouseEvent questions and answers *do* have permalinks - the link that appears when you click 'share' (see the tooltip for 'share'). Basically, permalinks are generally shorter, and **never change** - so yeah - you could take it as 'insurance' :)

Comment: @HackerKarma About your page issue, the tooltip says it links the _listing_.

Comment: @MouseEvent which page?